# How to conditionally apply a template filter in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Suppose I have a Django template with

```
<div><b>{{some.long.expression.with.stuff|filter1}}</b></div>
```

and I only wish to apply `filter1` if `my_condition` is True.

What is the best way?  Here is a verbose way with repetition:

```
{% if my_condition %}
<div><b>{{some.long.expression.with.stuff|filter1}}</b></div>
{% else %}
<div><b>{{some.long.expression.with.stuff}}</b></div>
{% endif %}
```

Here is slightly less verbose, harder to read, still with some repetition:

```
<div><b>{% if my_condition %}{{some.long.expression.with.stuff|filter1}}{% else %}{{some.long.expression.with.stuff}}{% endif %}</b></div>
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with a [**`{% with … %} … {% endwith %}`** template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with):

```
{% with somevar=some.long.expression.with.stuff %}
<div><b>{% if my_condition %}{{ somevar|filter1 }}{% else %}{{ somevar }}{% endif %}</b></div>
{% endwith %}
```